# Retry Patterns using Polly httpClient ConfigureAwait(true)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient, polly, retry-logic

```
 var appendFileResponse = await Policy
            .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(message => !message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)))
            .ExecuteAsync(async () => await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(true))
            .ConfigureAwait(true);

 if (appendFileResponse.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
 {
            throw new ApplicationException($"Failed to append file");
 }
```

I want to make sure `appendFileResponse` is completed before doing the If check and some other operations.

Should I add `ConfigureAwait(true)` in the `httpClient.SendAsync` call and/or `.ConfigureAwait(true)` in the await Policy?

Comment: Be careful with retrying when appending files, you could end up in a place where the request was processed successfully on the server but you never received a response.  Polly retry policy will kick in and send the request again, resulting in a duplicate append. A bit more engineering may be required to make sure this action is indempotent.

Answer (score 2):

`ConfigureAwait` has no effect on what order things run in. The fact that you're using `await` means that the code will "asynchronously wait" at that point.

`ConfigureAwait` just determines [which context your code is resuming on](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html): a captured context (the default), or the thread pool context (if you pass `false`).

The `if` is run after all the Polly retries regardless of whether or not you use `ConfigureAwait`.